# How to Autocomplete HTML Tags in TextMate?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, textmate

I'm going thru Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and, like him, using TextMate as my editor. Today, in chapter 3 of his tutorial, I saw him do something in TextMate I've not seen done before:

As he types a tag in a file called "whatever.html", the tag dynamically updates and creates a corresponding ending tag. So, as an example, if he's typed `<ht`, then TextMate automatically creates `<html></html>`, apparently on the fly.

I've found the keystrokes to autocomplete a tag, but this is a little different. Any ideas how this is being done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<kbd>opt/alt⌥</kbd><kbd>esc⎋</kbd> will autocomplete the tag name, <kbd>ctrl⌃</kbd><kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl⌃</kbd><kbd>shift⇧</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> will transform it into open and close tags.

Go to Bundles -> HTML -> Insert Tag menu to find other tag insertion keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

Check Bundles -> Html for all the different keystrokes you can use. I'm guessing this could be the Ctrl-< keystroke.

Comment: It's close, but I'd swear it's happening "live"... I'm watching a video screencast and watching his tags update as he types... I'll have to live with CTRL< for now, I guess!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link to a screencast on the Textmate website.  I had the same question that you have b/c I'm working through Michael Hartl's video tutorial, and I had to find out how he was doing this.

http://screencasts.textmate.org/insert_html_tags.mov

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

To get the open and close tags press the keys

Control Shift , 
 this is same as 
 Control <

Hope this helps.